# Delete sub list from main list

Tags: c#, list, model-view-controller, identity

I'm working at MVC Identity, and want to get the roles the user didn't have, so I created `usersWithRoles` LINQ, contains the roles add to user, and `Roles` list contains all roles, so I need to remove `usersWithRoles` from `Roles` to get a new List contains the roles that the user didn't have them,
this is my code:

```
public JsonResult GetUserRolesToAdd(string Username)
{
    var usersWithRoles = (from user in context.Users.Where(u => u.UserName == Username)
                          select new
                          {
                              UserRoles = (from userRole in user.Roles
                                           join role in context.Roles on userRole.RoleId equals role.Id
                                           select new { RoleName = role.Name, RoleId = role.Id }).ToList()
                          }).ToList();

    var RolesToAdd = (from roles in context.Roles
                      select new
                      {
                          RoleId = roles.Name
                      }).ToList();

    foreach (var item in usersWithRoles)
        RolesToAdd.Remove(
                         //what to write inside removeAll function!
                          );

    var jsonResult = Json(usersWithRoles, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    jsonResult.MaxJsonLength = int.MaxValue;
    return jsonResult;
}
```

any one can help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about `.Except()` ?

```
var userRoles = new List<string>();
var allRoles = new List<string>();

var missingRoles = allRoles.Except(userRoles);
```

It will filter `allRoles` by removing all roles contained in `userRoles`.

Please see [MS doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.except?view=netframework-4.7.2).

Comment: note that the first list contains a variable that holds the list!

Comment: I'm just pointing you to the right direction. Get the first list, iterate over it and you will be able to have these two lists of roles.

Comment: If your username is unique, get only one user with that username and you will have these two lists of roles.